# Is web Token(enterprises.webTokens) is reusable?

Tags: android-management-api

https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.webTokens#resource:-webtoken

A web token used to access the managed Google Play iframe.
Is this web token will expire after some time or we can store the token and use it?

Comment: Did you test it?

Comment: @marsh-wiggle Yes. I checked with already created web token. It is working.
But I don't know Whether It wok all time or after some time it will expire.

Answer (score 0):

When we look at the response header of embedded iframe, we see the fields:  "expires" (**outdated**) and "Cache-Control" (**no-cache**). This means that the response is considered out of date, it should only be used once.

The iframe will therefore be invalidated in the near future.

[outdated iframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lVy3.png)
[cache-control field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ryUH.png)

Answer (score 0):

A newly generated web token can be re-used for up to 4 hours after it was generated. Once the token expires, it cannot be used again and you should generate a new web token.

Comment: How to handle expiry events ? I can't see any documentation around it and yes it dose expire after sometime.